# What does <%# mean in aspx files

Tags: asp.net

Never done aspx before.  Trying to fix a bug.

I've tracked it down to this line of code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProject_Edit" selectedvalue='<%# Bind("ProjectsId") %>' runat="server"  CssClass="ddl" DataSourceID="dsProject_Edit" DataTextField="DESCRIPTION" DataValueField="BOUND_"></asp:DropDownList>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: 'ddlProject_Edit' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
```

So I'm guessing that it has something to do with the `<%# Bind("ProjectsId") %>` piece.

What does `<%#` do?  Googling such characters hasn't proved very fruitful.

What would be even more helpful is an explaination as to what `Bind("ProjectsId")` is doing exactly.

Comment: Try to debug and watch the value of ProjectsId to see if it has a value that does not belong to the list of possible values of your dropdownlist. It could be a null or -1 value and thus causing this error

Comment: I'm just looking at this file in a text editor - no debug facilities

Comment: I see you have set "BOUND_" column of your database table to hold all the possible values in the dropdownlist. And the selected value is in the "ProjectsId" column. Try to check your database records to see if there is a value in the "ProjectsId" column that does not exist in the "BOUND_" column

Comment: That includes null values too

Comment: Didn't have a column called ProjectsId, but did have one called id and delting those bad rows solved the problem - - thank you  user3340627

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [Data Binding Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx(v=vs.100).aspx).

Supposedly there are two sets of data at play here:

- A set of items to populate the options in the `DropDownList`
- A set of records in a repeater/grid/etc. of some sort which contains the `DropDownList`

What this code is doing is basically saying:

> For the record that this "row" represents, set the value of this control to the `ProjectsId` value in that record.

As for the *error*, what's happening is that the record has a value which doesn't exist in the `DropDownList`.  To illustrate, let's say you have a `DropDownList` with the following items:

- Apple
- Orange
- Banana

What's happening here is that the record has the value `"Pear"`.  So the system can't set the value in the `DropDownList` because that value doesn't exist.

The underlying *problem* behind this is that the data is bad.  There is broken referential integrity in the data.  A record has a lookup value which doesn't exist.  Either the data needs to be corrected, or the application can no longer assume that the data will be correct and has to account for that.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, it's a [data-binding expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx).

As stated in the link:

> [data binding] allows you to bind control property values to data and specify values
>   for retrieving, updating, deleting, and inserting data.
>
> The Bind function is used for two-way (updatable) binding. In addition
>   to calling Eval and Bind methods to perform data binding in a
>   data-binding expression, you can call any publicly scoped code within
>   the <%# and %> delimiters to execute that code and return a value
>   during page processing.

By binding the `SelectedValue`, it is effectively causing the value to be set when the control is data bound.

Answer (score 2):

The symbol # in the aspnet forms code means binding to a field so it is needed to use it before Bind("ProjectsId"). Your problem is that the selected value set in the binding is not in the list of items filled in the dropdown or maybe the binding occurs before the dropdown list is filled.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%#   %>
```

These are the brackets used by asp .Net to set the areas will be used by codebehind codes.

```
 <%# Bind("ProjectsId") %>
```

This line simply tells compiler to set the starting value of the dropdownlist to  ProjectsId value, which will be sent from codebehind.

Your error message:

```
Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: 'ddlProject_Edit' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
```

This tells you that the value sent from codebehind wasn't match with any value in the dropdownlist.